# Python requests session sending using wrong method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Due to requests adding unwanted headers, I decided to prepare the request manually and use Session Send().

Sadly, The following code produces the wrong request

```
import requests

ARCHIVE_URL = "http://10.0.0.10/post/tmp/archive.zip"

headers = {
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
 'Host': '10.0.0.10'
}

DataToSend = 'data'

req = requests.Request('POST', ARCHIVE_URL, data=DataToSend, headers=headers)
prepped = req.prepare()
s = requests.Session()
response = s.send(prepped)
```

If I look at the request using fiddler I get this:

```
GET http://10.0.0.10/tmp/archive.zip HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: 10.0.0.10
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you must add headers what server expects from you bt what errors are you getting

Comment: @Argus the behavior is identical with headers, I only removed it to simplify the code. see updated code

Answer (score 0):

since prepared request is not connected to the session when using   req.prepare() instead of  s.prepare_request(req) when s is the session , you **must** specify request headers since there are no default one that come from the session object.

use  s.prepare_request(req) instead of req.prepare()  or specify headers dictionary

Comment: See updated code. the behavior is identical with the headers.
I also tried to use prepare_request instead, still the same behavior...

Comment: try write your data as dictionary like so : DataToSend ={'data':'data'}

Comment: Didn't help :/
I end up just using the normal requests.post()